# How to use laravel classes in custom queue

Tags: queue, laravel-4

I cant use laravel classes in my custom queue. Eg:

`Queue::push('Custom\NameSpace\For\Class', array('status' => $data));`

---

```
// queue class
namespace App\Queues;

class QueueTwitterStatus
{
    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        // log class not found :(
        Log::info('Log me');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

backslash :  `\Log::info('Log me');`

Answer (score 1):

You can also import the Log class using the [**use** operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). I prefer this method because it keeps things clean.

```
// queue class
namespace App\Queues;

use Log;

class QueueTwitterStatus
{
    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        Log::info('Log me');
    }
}
```